# How can I avoid DRY with a const-referee and non-const-referee version of a class?

Tags: c++, constants, dry, idioms

I have some class which looks like this:

```
struct A {
  void *stuff;
  int x;

  int foo() const;
}
```

And I have some functions which take parameters of this type, e.g.

```
int bar(A a1, A2 a2);
int baz(A2 a2);
```

The thing is, not all of these functions actually change any memory in `a2.stuff`; yet - I can't take a `const void*` and an `int`, construct an A and pass it to such functions. Or rather, I can, but only using `const_cast<>` which is really not the way to live your life. Plus, I could easily get confused and pass my `const_cast<>`'ed A to a function which actually modifies data through `A::stuff`.

So, I decided I want a "constant A". Not an A whose fields are immutable - an A through which you don't change what stuff points to.

If A was somehow templated, i.e. if it the short was some kind of `T` - then no problem, you replace `A<void>` with A`<const void>` and Bjarne's your uncle. But... A isn't templated. And I don't want to make it templated, since I don't want `A<int>`'s or anything like that to exist.

So, what should I do?

The naive approach is to replicate the definition of A, almost, for a `const_A`:

```
struct const_A {
  void const *stuff;
  int x;

  int foo() const;
}

struct A {
  void *stuff;
  int x;

  int foo() const;
  operator const_A() const { return const_A { stuff, x }; }
}
```

but that's repetitive, and if I have 20 methods it's even more annoying to replicate.

Bonus points for a solution without a lot of boilerplate, private members, implementation of all ctors etc.

Comment: `using const_A = const A;`.  Or the Apple Cocoa way of having `struct NSString` (which is immutable) and `struct NSMutableString : NSString` (which is mutable).  The immutability is via interface, rather than `const`.

Comment: @Eljay: About your first suggestion - read the question more carefully, that doesn't do what you think it does. About your second suggestion - please elaborate.

Comment: Is `const_A` supposed to have `void const* stuff;`?

Comment: Apple Cocoa is Objective-C, so it's OO approach is different than C++.  The gist is you can given an immutable class you can have a mutable class derived from it.  Your interfaces can use the immutable class when appropriate, and the longer named mutable class when needed.  The implementation will probably use copy-on-write to optimize the mutable case.  (The immutability is by design, not by a core language feature.)

Comment: @Eljay: Ah, yes, sorry, fixed that.

Comment: You might be able to get away with using a non-type template parameter `template <bool stuffIsConst>` and then using `std::conditional_t<stuffIsConst, void const*, void*>` to avoid repeated definitions

Comment: Timer expired on updating my original comment, so I'll leave it for posterity.  (Hence my suggestion, which is now irrelevant.)

Comment: [std::experimental::propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) ?

Comment: @Jarod42: Oh, nice! That sounds promising :-)  ... what do you think about the inheritance approach though?

Comment: @NathanPierson: Perhaps with a couple more using's to hide the templates? I don't want to write `A<true>` and `A<false>` everywhere.

Comment: @Jarod42: How long is an implementation of `propagata_const` though?

Comment: `propagate_const` has few methods, None seems complicated, either specialization for pointer type (versus pointer-like type as smart pointer), or simple SFINAE should do the job.

Comment: Perhaps too late, but you wrote "if I have 20 methods it's even more annoying to replicate". Does that mean you have control over methods and can modify or they written and no longer modifiable?

Comment: @vish: Well, if I can rewrite A then obviously I have control over which methods A has.

Answer (score 3):

A solution based on the idea of  [`std::experimental::propagate_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const):

```
namespace detail {
struct const_propagating_void_ptr {
    void* ptr;

    operator void       *()       { return ptr; }
    operator void const *() const { return ptr; }
};
} // namespace detail

struct A {
  detail::const_propagating_void_ptr stuff_;
  int x;

  int foo() const;
  void       * stuff()       { return stuff_; }
  void const * stuff() const { return stuff_; }
};
```

Pros:

- [Rule of Zero](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/04/23/the-rule-of-zero-zero-constructor-zero-calorie/) (also known as [C++ Core Guideline C.20](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-zero)) FTW.
- In fact, `A` and the pointer-like class are just plain old structs!
- You can reuse the pointer-like class (or even templatize it) elsewhere, so it's more text but not that much.

Cons:

- ```
  const A a1 {my_ptr, 123};
  A a2 {a1};
  *a2.stuff() = 456; // ... and a1's pointer is used for write access :-(
  ```

  This [compiles without warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/8rTE39ofY). Thanks goes to @AyxanHaqverdili for pointing this out.
- Can't construct a `const A` from a `const void*` and an `int` (without const_cast'ing).
- Doesn't actually protect the const-propagator from direct access; but at least such access would have to be explicit. We could disable it by actually using `std::experimental::propagate_const`, which probably has a protected data member, overrides assignment and move-assignment operators etc.

---

**Q:** Why not just have the getters in `A`, and use a `void*`?

**A:** A user of `A` may easily make the mistake of accessing `A::stuff_` instead of `A::stuff()`. If that were just a `void *`, the chance of accidentally writing to `A::stuff_` would be quite high. But with this solution, to get to the `void*` you need to write: `A::stuff_::ptr`, and nobody will write `my_a.stuff.ptr` instead of `my_a.stuff()` by mistake.

Comment: "old" way is to provide 2 getters: `void* getStuff() {return stuff;} const void* getStuff() const {return stuff;}`.

Comment: @Jarod42: I actually do that, I just don't use that name prefix.

Comment: `ptr` should be private BTW.

Comment: the benefit using `detail::const_propagating_void_ptr` instead of `void*` in this code is not really clear. (`stuff()` doens't really need it to work)

Comment: @appleapple: I'll explain the benefits in the answer.

Comment: @Jarod42: You want to take away the awesome PODness? :-(

Comment: @einpoklum oh I'm just saying the `stuff()` overload is confusing (there is really no benefit shown *in this code* over `void*`).

Comment: @einpoklum re-edit: well, nothing would happens  when we try to construct an `A` from a `const A`. (just like plain `void*`)

Comment: @einpoklum btw, I think rule of zero is about managing resource. (which doesn't happens in `A`) (and is not what `propagate_const` aim for, but smart pointer)

Comment: @appleapple: The Rule of Zero is more about the single-responsibility principle; resource management is the most prominent example where a class handles more responsibility than it probably should, and that responsibility can be delegated to its members.

Comment: @einpoklum I believe it actually comes from rule of 3/5/0 and is really only about managing resource https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: @appleapple: If you read that page, you'll see it's really not only about managing resources.

Comment: @einpoklum The page absolutely say language default (and that whole section is about managing resource), not sure what language default you have here?

Comment: @einpoklum and what benefit on that over `void*`? Nothing (at least in your code).

Answer (score 1):

One solution, which @Eljay suggests in a comment, is to have the mutable A inherit the immutable A, which is a common idiom of Objective-C.

Perhaps something along these lines:

```
struct const_A {
  const void *stuff_;
  int x;

  const void* stuff() const { return stuff_; }
  int foo() const;
}

struct A : public const_A {
  void* stuff() const { return const_cast<void*>(stuff_); }
}
```

?

Drawbacks:

- Can no longer write `A{ &my_stuff, 123 }`.

Comment: @MirceaIspas: As it is the OP who answers :-) expectations should be known. (but `const_cast` remark remains).

Comment: @MirceaIspas: Yeah, fixed.

Comment: Please don't call it immutable, because it's not.  When I do similar things, I've been calling it "readable".  `const&` are readable, rather than immutable.

Comment: The **D** programming language has the concepts of something being mutable, or `const`, or `immutable`.  (There is a distinction for `const` and `immutable` when used as a parameter qualifier, with what it imposes on the caller's argument.)  In C++ `const` is shallow, but in **D** `const` is always deep (transitive).  I wish C++ had deep `const`.  A deep `const` object can be shared across threads without locking.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @einpoklum, I was thinking of using a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
#include <variant>

struct const_A {
  std::variant<void*, const void*> stuff_;
  int x;

  int foo() const;
  void* stuff() { return std::get<0>(stuff_); }
  const void* stuff() const { return std::get<1>(stuff_); }
};

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this better? `<variant>` is 1741 lines of code, and a bunch of template instantiations; my helper class is 6 lines (+2 for the namespace). Even you templated it and bullet-proofed it like Jarod42 suggested, it would still be... what, maybe 12 lines? What's more, a variant requires more space.

Comment: ... on the other hand, if you're writing slide-ware, or teaching this to students, then yeah, I guess I can see the benefit of using a "vocabulary class". +1.

Comment: @einpoklum, I was thinking that you can also use a visitor to add constantness for member functions that are happy with `const void*`. However, the more I re-read the problem statement, I am wondering if the OP is describing a [std::weak_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr).

Comment: 1. I'm the OP... 2. No, this is not like weak_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can also work, but the template stuff has to be propagated all over the place:

```
template<bool IsConst> 
struct A
{
    std::conditional_t<IsConst, const void*, void*> _stuff;
    int x;

    int foo() const;
};
```

Comment: But then I would have to say `A<true>` and `A<false>` everywhere. :-(

Comment: I see this was already proposed in the comments. I can delete this answer

Comment: @einpoklum you can make aliases, like `using ConstA = A<true>` / `using NonConstA = A<false>`;

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the question-comment discussion... but if you add it to your answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: Also - this does not allow A to be used as a const_A.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I asked for ability to change the functions is because there can be external non-technical reasons why you may not.

This is what I came up with using seldom used "using" syntax (at least I have not seen it almost ever):

```
  struct A {
     A(void* stuff, int x) : stuff_(stuff), x_(x) {}
     const void* const_stuff() const { return stuff_; }
     void* stuff() { return stuff_; }
     int foo() const;
     
  private:
     void *stuff_;
     int x_;

  };

  struct const_A : private A {
     const_A(void* stuff, int x) : A(stuff, x) {}

  private:
     using A::stuff;
  public:
     using A::const_stuff;
     using A::foo;
  };

  void doSomethingWith_const_A(const_A& c) {
     const void * stuff = c.const_stuff();
     // void * v = c.stuff(); //won't work
  }

  void doSomethingWith_const_A(const const_A& c) {
     const void * stuff = c.const_stuff();
     //void * v = c.stuff(); //won't work
  }
  void doSomethingWith_A(A& a) {
     void * stuff = a.stuff();
     const void * const_stuff = a.const_stuff(); //okay
  }


  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
     A Aobj(nullptr, 0);
     const_A const_Aobj(nullptr, 0);
     doSomethingWith_const_A(const_Aobj);
     doSomethingWith_A(Aobj);
     doSomethingWith_A(const_Aobj);
  }
```

Comment: How is this better from [my own inheritance-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68226732/1593077)? It's certainly more costly, in that you're using a vtable. Also, `_tmain()`? `_TCHAR*`?

Comment: @einpoklum  I have removed `virtual`; not needed. _TCHAR, _tmain - Visual Studio. I have also used private inheritance now. That would disallow const_A -> conversion impossible.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're inverting the inheritance relation: The const class now inherits the non-const. I now see the difference.