# Can a C++ constructor know whether it's constructing a const object?

Tags: c++, reflection, constants, construction

In C++, object constructors cannot be const-qualified.

But - can the constructor of an object of class `A` know whether it's constructing a `const A` or a non-const `A`?

<sub>Motivated by a fine point in the discussion regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68226516/1593077).</sub>

Comment: That discussion lead me to write [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mqo736Gee). Looks like gcc zeros out the buffer afterwards for some reason. [Nerd Sniping](https://xkcd.com/356/) is a thing!

Comment: For your use case, is a constructor `enum Tag { Mut, Const };` acceptable?  So you'd do `Foo foo{Mut};` or `Foo const cfoo{Const};` ... which means it's manual, and if someone messes up it'll be annoying to track down the mistake.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: I'm not sure how that program relates to the question, but - if I am not mistaken, reading from where an object has been destructed is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Eljay: Obviously if you _tell_ your constructor what you're constructing, it can tell you right back. No cheating...

Comment: @einpoklum the relation was to change buffer only using a const pointer.

Comment: I don't think the constructor knows if the object is being *born const*.  You can mutate the member variables in the body of the constructor.  If there was a `Foo() const { ... }` constructor, then that would be the hook.  So I think you'll need to cheat, or double-down cheat and use a MACRO.  Or take a page out of JavaScript, and add a `freeze()` method that sets a flag which is vetted for mutating methods and throws if tripped.

Comment: The answer that was deleted which used passing a pointer of the object into the constructor needs a catchy name.  I propose **CUCP** "Curiously Uncommon Constructor Pattern".  Regarding Ayxan's Nerd Sniping:  programmers are only worth one point.

Answer (score 3):

No, because copy elision (and the so-called guaranteed copy elision) can **change** the constness of an object "after" construction:

```
struct A {
  bool c;
  A() : c(magic_i_am_const()) {}
  A(const A&)=delete;      // immovable
};

const A f() {return {};}
A g() {return f();}        // OK
void h() {
  A x=f();                 // OK
  const A y=g();           // OK
}
```

What should `x.c` and `y.c` be?

Comment: Your example is a bit boring, since `x` and `y` are created only once (by variable definition) and thus their constness doesn't change.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: I figured it was clearer to illustrate with prvalues, which have but one set of semantics, even though it’s hard to say what the constness of an unmaterialized prvalue means.  If you switch to NRVO, you (can) get multiple non-reference variables with different *cv*-qualifications that are all the same object, although one could argue that that’s not quite “changing” either.